# How to exclude fields from print page version (html, pdf)?

Tags: theming, files

As in question, excluding node fields from HTML print page is easy via CSS, but what about PDF version (PDF version module)?

Answer (score 4):

A quick peek in the code shows that the [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module utilizes "[View Modes](http://drupalcode.org/project/print.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/print.module#l377)", which is a good thing. More info in [Entity view mode](https://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) and [Drupal 7 custom node view modes](http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes).

You should create a new suitable view mode or re-use one you already have. This allows you to control the settings with the Field UI, while still allowing you custom templates if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You can try overriding the print template (print.tpl.php). The default template for that is in the directory of the print module. That's if you're using Drupal 6.